# The difference between 2 Instants in Calendar Days

Tags: java, temporal, java.time.instant

So I'm trying to get a specific number with my code. Right now I have:

```
Instant Today = 2018-07-17T13:45:00Z
Instant Expiration1 = 2018-07-18T11:00:00Z
long daysTilExp = Today.until(Expiration, Chronounit.DAYS)
```

The problem is that because this isn't exactly 24 hours apart it ends up returning `daysTilExp = 0` but I want `daysTilExp = 1` I'm trying to get that actual days apart the two Instants are so then even If I change the value of Expiration like so:

```
Instant Expiration1 = 2018-07-18T06:00:00Z
```

and now `daysTilExp = 2`. I looked at some other answers on StackOverflow but it doesn't look like people are using `Instant` and they aren't wanting the difference the same way

Comment: Are you sure that your second example results in `2`?

Comment: @DominikSandjaja No I want the result to be `2` It would return a `1` as the real answer

Comment: Please, post the code which compiles. You cant parse `2018-07-17T13:45:00Z` directly to `Instant`, it's not even the String, how is it supposed to work? Use the camelCase with the lower-cased first letter as a variable name. Isn't `Chronounit` supposed to be `ChronoUnit`?

Comment: Please explain how the interval from 1:45 PM on Tuesday to 6 AM the following day constitutes two days.  It’s not even one full day.  Did you mean to write `2018-07-19`?

Comment: You need to choose a time zone for that. It is never the same calendar date everywhere on Earth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LocalDate will remove the time part and LocalDate objects comparison will yield the expected result:

```
LocalDateTime  today = LocalDateTime.parse("2018-07-17T13:45:00");
LocalDateTime  expiration = LocalDateTime.parse("2018-07-18T11:00:00");
LocalDate todayDate = today.toLocalDate();
LocalDate expirationDate = expiration.toLocalDate();
long days = todayDate.until(expirationDate, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
System.out.println(days);
```

Comment: You can just parse it directly to a localdate but you got me there so thanks.

Comment: @TOTOROCATBUS You can, but only of you want the count in UTC will it give you the correct dates.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes it does

Comment: LocalDate has a parse method but it accepts 2 parameters: date as string and timezone.

Comment: @PavelMolchanov [The Java 9 `LocalDate` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) mentions two `parse` methods, but none takes a time zone argument. What did you mean, please?

Comment: You are right. It doesn't take timezone :) I tried to use LocalDate to parse the date with the time part but it wasn't working because parser was not able to parse time part.

Answer (score 4):

The best way is using `DAYS.between()` method from `java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit`. But this way works only for Java 8+ versions. Example:

```
Date start = new Date();
Date end = new Date(start.getTime() + 10_000);
long daysCount = DAYS.between(start.toInstant(), end.toInstant());
```

Comment: Very good suggestion for Java 8+  Also for difference in SECONDS (or other units) between Instants java.time.Instant !  
Example: ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between( t0 ,Instant.now());

Minor thing: in your code should read "end.toInstant()" (not toInstance() )

Answer (score 2):

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/Chicago");

    Instant today = Instant.parse("2018-07-18T17:15:00Z");
    Instant expiration1 = Instant.parse("2018-07-19T05:00:00Z");

    ZonedDateTime todayInZone = today.atZone(zone);
    ZonedDateTime expirationInZone = expiration1.atZone(zone);
    long daysTilExp = todayInZone.toLocalDate().until(expirationInZone, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
    System.out.format("From %s to %s is %d day/s.%n", 
                      todayInZone, expirationInZone, daysTilExp);
```

> From 2018-07-18T12:15-05:00[America/Chicago] to 2018-07-19T00:00-05:00[America/Chicago] is 1 day/s.

So from July 18 to 19 is 1 day. If you wanted both inclusive in the count, just add 1.

Since it is never the same date everywhere on Earth, counting days is different in different time zones. Try changing the time zone and keeping the same instants:

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Tokyo");
```

This changes the output to

> From 2018-07-19T02:15+09:00[Asia/Tokyo] to 2018-07-19T14:00+09:00[Asia/Tokyo] is 0 day/s.

As you can read from the output, this is because it is now already July 19 in Japan, so it os counting from July 19 to 19 and getting 0.

So you need to choose in which time zone you want your count.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
long daysTilExp = (long) Math.ceil(now.until(goodTo, ChronoUnit.HOURS) / 24.0);
```